# if else statement is not working on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

i have few if else statement on returning just true or false, and every statement is not working properly. i have tried many ways but don't know the problem.it will be very helpful if anyone fix this.

here is my code for model

```
function exists($email){
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $query=$this->db->get('member_info');
    echo "model is called"; // after execution this text is shown but not the others
    if ($query->num_rows == 1) {           
        return true;        
        echo "i got one";
    }else{
        return false;
        echo "i got nothing";
    }       
}
```

and here is my controller

```
function is_exists($email){
    echo "this is loaded";  //this line works properly
    if($this->validation_model->exists($email)){
        return false;
        echo "true"; //this doesn't 
    }else{
        return true;
        echo "false"; // this doesn't
    }
}
```

Comment: $query->num_rows() try this

Comment: Nothing after `return` will run. `return` exits the function.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning the function before you print the echo part. You should echo before the return.

Also change the line to check more than one

if ($query->num_rows() > 0 ) {

### Update

Try this method. replace the table name, id value accordingly.

```
$query = $this->db->query("select id form your_table where email=".$email);
if ($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
echo "i got one";
return true;
}
else{
echo "i got nothing";
return false;
}
```

Also look at your controller logic it return false when there exist an email. It is better to change the true false returning of controller.

Comment: +1 This makes sense. It will be useful if you write some code also.

Comment: i the model the result is always true (it gets an email in the db,when the input email is totally new).what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
if($this->validation_model->exists($email)){
    echo "true";
    return false; 
}else{
    echo "false";
    return true;
}
```

put the echo before `return`,and it should be like

```
$query->num_rows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `return`, code after `return` will not execute

```
return false;
echo "true"; // this doesn't because you have return before this line

return true;
echo "false"; // this doesn't because you have return before this line
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if ($query->num_rows == 1) {
```

to this:

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
```

And change the following:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
    echo "i got one";
    return true;
}
else{
    echo "i got nothing";
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//num_rows() is a function
<?php 

function exists($email){
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $query=$this->db->get('member_info');
    echo "model is called"; // after execution this text is shown but not the others

    //num_rows() is a function
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {

        //add message before return statement
        echo "i got one";
        return true;


    }else{

        echo "i got nothing";
        return false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be:

```
if ($query->num_rows == 1) {           
    return true;        
}else{
    return false;
}
```

no need to print additional echo. Same story with your controller

```
if($this->validation_model->exists($email)){
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

as far as i know you cannot execute any code after a return statement (in the function returning).

My Solution would be:

in your controller put it like this

```
if($this->validation_model->exists($email)){
    echo "EMAIL EXIST";
}else{
    echo "EMAIL DOES NOT EXIST";
}
```